# error installing Caffe on Mac 10.12 (Sierra) "symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64"

Tags: macos, opencv, caffe, macos-sierra

i have been trying to set up Caffe on my macbook for three days now... maybe you can help me?

i followed several tutorials including these:

- the official berkeley vision caffe installation guide
- https://gist.github.com/kylemcdonald/0698c7749e483cd43a0e
- https://eddiesmo.wordpress.com/2016/12/20/how-to-set-up-caffe-environment-and-pycaffe-on-os-x-10-12-sierra/

but whenever i try to run

```
make all
```

i get this error:

```
LD -o .build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0

clang: warning: argument unused during compilation: '-pthread'

Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

  "cv::String::deallocate()", referenced from:   
    caffe::WindowDataLayer<float>::load_batch(caffe::Batch<float>*) in window_data_layer.o

..............
..............
..............

ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

make: *** [.build_release/lib/libcaffe.so.1.0.0] Error 1
```

here's what i did so far:

- i was originally on mac os 10.11 el capitan with an outdated xcode (7.3). in order to update xcode i had to upgrade to Sierra (mac os 10.12)
- i have xcode 8 now, but downgraded the xcode command line tools to 7.3.2. (i can't remember why but it was recommended for Caffe or maybe CUDA)
- i don't have an NVIDIA graphics card but still installed CUDA (from what i read online it's a prerequisite for caffe)... i tried cuda 7 (as recommended on the berkeley vision site) and currently cuda 8
- right now i'm using CUDA-8
- i used homebrew to install opencv as recommended online (opencv 2.4.13.2)
- i use openBLAS
- i use protobuf 3.3.0
- i added `opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_core opencv_imgcodecs` to `LIBRARIES` in Makefile
- i realize that the linker errors have to do with **libc++ vs libstdc++** ! i manually checked all kinds of dependencies with `otool -L` to see if any still used `libstdc++` but it seems they should all be built with `libc++`.

any hints or advice?
pls help!

thank you!

---

Makefile

```
PROJECT := caffe

CONFIG_FILE := Makefile.config
# Explicitly check for the config file, otherwise make -k will proceed anyway.
ifeq ($(wildcard $(CONFIG_FILE)),)
$(error $(CONFIG_FILE) not found. See $(CONFIG_FILE).example.)
endif
include $(CONFIG_FILE)

BUILD_DIR_LINK := $(BUILD_DIR)
ifeq ($(RELEASE_BUILD_DIR),)
    RELEASE_BUILD_DIR := .$(BUILD_DIR)_release
endif
ifeq ($(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR),)
    DEBUG_BUILD_DIR := .$(BUILD_DIR)_debug
endif

DEBUG ?= 0
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    BUILD_DIR := $(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)
    OTHER_BUILD_DIR := $(RELEASE_BUILD_DIR)
else
    BUILD_DIR := $(RELEASE_BUILD_DIR)
    OTHER_BUILD_DIR := $(DEBUG_BUILD_DIR)
endif

# All of the directories containing code.
SRC_DIRS := $(shell find * -type d -exec bash -c "find {} -maxdepth 1 \
    \( -name '*.cpp' -o -name '*.proto' \) | grep -q ." \; -print)

# The target shared library name
LIBRARY_NAME := $(PROJECT)
LIB_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/lib
STATIC_NAME := $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/lib$(LIBRARY_NAME).a
DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR       := 1
DYNAMIC_VERSION_MINOR       := 0
DYNAMIC_VERSION_REVISION    := 0
DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT := lib$(LIBRARY_NAME).so
#DYNAMIC_SONAME_SHORT := $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR)
DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT := $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MINOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_REVISION)
DYNAMIC_NAME := $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)/$(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT)
COMMON_FLAGS += -DCAFFE_VERSION=$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MAJOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_MINOR).$(DYNAMIC_VERSION_REVISION)

##############################
# Get all source files
##############################
# CXX_SRCS are the source files excluding the test ones.
CXX_SRCS := $(shell find src/$(PROJECT) ! -name "test_*.cpp" -name "*.cpp")
# CU_SRCS are the cuda source files
CU_SRCS := $(shell find src/$(PROJECT) ! -name "test_*.cu" -name "*.cu")
# TEST_SRCS are the test source files
TEST_MAIN_SRC := src/$(PROJECT)/test/test_caffe_main.cpp
TEST_SRCS := $(shell find src/$(PROJECT) -name "test_*.cpp")
TEST_SRCS := $(filter-out $(TEST_MAIN_SRC), $(TEST_SRCS))
TEST_CU_SRCS := $(shell find src/$(PROJECT) -name "test_*.cu")
GTEST_SRC := src/gtest/gtest-all.cpp
# TOOL_SRCS are the source files for the tool binaries
TOOL_SRCS := $(shell find tools -name "*.cpp")
# EXAMPLE_SRCS are the source files for the example binaries
EXAMPLE_SRCS := $(shell find examples -name "*.cpp")
# BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR contains any generated header files we want to include.
BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/src
# PROTO_SRCS are the protocol buffer definitions
PROTO_SRC_DIR := src/$(PROJECT)/proto
PROTO_SRCS := $(wildcard $(PROTO_SRC_DIR)/*.proto)
# PROTO_BUILD_DIR will contain the .cc and obj files generated from
# PROTO_SRCS; PROTO_BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR will contain the .h header files
PROTO_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(PROTO_SRC_DIR)
PROTO_BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR := $(BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR)/$(PROJECT)/proto
# NONGEN_CXX_SRCS includes all source/header files except those generated
# automatically (e.g., by proto).
NONGEN_CXX_SRCS := $(shell find \
    src/$(PROJECT) \
    include/$(PROJECT) \
    python/$(PROJECT) \
    matlab/+$(PROJECT)/private \
    examples \
    tools \
    -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.hpp" -or -name "*.cu" -or -name "*.cuh")
LINT_SCRIPT := scripts/cpp_lint.py
LINT_OUTPUT_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/.lint
LINT_EXT := lint.txt
LINT_OUTPUTS := $(addsuffix .$(LINT_EXT), $(addprefix $(LINT_OUTPUT_DIR)/, $(NONGEN_CXX_SRCS)))
EMPTY_LINT_REPORT := $(BUILD_DIR)/.$(LINT_EXT)
NONEMPTY_LINT_REPORT := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(LINT_EXT)
# PY$(PROJECT)_SRC is the python wrapper for $(PROJECT)
PY$(PROJECT)_SRC := python/$(PROJECT)/_$(PROJECT).cpp
PY$(PROJECT)_SO := python/$(PROJECT)/_$(PROJECT).so
PY$(PROJECT)_HXX := include/$(PROJECT)/layers/python_layer.hpp
# MAT$(PROJECT)_SRC is the mex entrance point of matlab package for $(PROJECT)
MAT$(PROJECT)_SRC := matlab/+$(PROJECT)/private/$(PROJECT)_.cpp
ifneq ($(MATLAB_DIR),)
    MAT_SO_EXT := $(shell $(MATLAB_DIR)/bin/mexext)
endif
MAT$(PROJECT)_SO := matlab/+$(PROJECT)/private/$(PROJECT)_.$(MAT_SO_EXT)

##############################
# Derive generated files
##############################
# The generated files for protocol buffers
PROTO_GEN_HEADER_SRCS := $(addprefix $(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/, \
        $(notdir ${PROTO_SRCS:.proto=.pb.h}))
PROTO_GEN_HEADER := $(addprefix $(PROTO_BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR)/, \
        $(notdir ${PROTO_SRCS:.proto=.pb.h}))
PROTO_GEN_CC := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${PROTO_SRCS:.proto=.pb.cc})
PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR := python/$(PROJECT)/proto
PY_PROTO_INIT := python/$(PROJECT)/proto/__init__.py
PROTO_GEN_PY := $(foreach file,${PROTO_SRCS:.proto=_pb2.py}, \
        $(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/$(notdir $(file)))
# The objects corresponding to the source files
# These objects will be linked into the final shared library, so we
# exclude the tool, example, and test objects.
CXX_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o})
CU_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/, ${CU_SRCS:.cu=.o})
PROTO_OBJS := ${PROTO_GEN_CC:.cc=.o}
OBJS := $(PROTO_OBJS) $(CXX_OBJS) $(CU_OBJS)
# tool, example, and test objects
TOOL_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${TOOL_SRCS:.cpp=.o})
TOOL_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/tools
TEST_CXX_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/src/$(PROJECT)/test
TEST_CU_BUILD_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/src/$(PROJECT)/test
TEST_CXX_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${TEST_SRCS:.cpp=.o})
TEST_CU_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/, ${TEST_CU_SRCS:.cu=.o})
TEST_OBJS := $(TEST_CXX_OBJS) $(TEST_CU_OBJS)
GTEST_OBJ := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${GTEST_SRC:.cpp=.o})
EXAMPLE_OBJS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${EXAMPLE_SRCS:.cpp=.o})
# Output files for automatic dependency generation
DEPS := ${CXX_OBJS:.o=.d} ${CU_OBJS:.o=.d} ${TEST_CXX_OBJS:.o=.d} \
    ${TEST_CU_OBJS:.o=.d} $(BUILD_DIR)/${MAT$(PROJECT)_SO:.$(MAT_SO_EXT)=.d}
# tool, example, and test bins
TOOL_BINS := ${TOOL_OBJS:.o=.bin}
EXAMPLE_BINS := ${EXAMPLE_OBJS:.o=.bin}
# symlinks to tool bins without the ".bin" extension
TOOL_BIN_LINKS := ${TOOL_BINS:.bin=}
# Put the test binaries in build/test for convenience.
TEST_BIN_DIR := $(BUILD_DIR)/test
TEST_CU_BINS := $(addsuffix .testbin,$(addprefix $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/, \
        $(foreach obj,$(TEST_CU_OBJS),$(basename $(notdir $(obj))))))
TEST_CXX_BINS := $(addsuffix .testbin,$(addprefix $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/, \
        $(foreach obj,$(TEST_CXX_OBJS),$(basename $(notdir $(obj))))))
TEST_BINS := $(TEST_CXX_BINS) $(TEST_CU_BINS)
# TEST_ALL_BIN is the test binary that links caffe dynamically.
TEST_ALL_BIN := $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/test_all.testbin

##############################
# Derive compiler warning dump locations
##############################
WARNS_EXT := warnings.txt
CXX_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${CXX_SRCS:.cpp=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
CU_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/, ${CU_SRCS:.cu=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
TOOL_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${TOOL_SRCS:.cpp=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
EXAMPLE_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${EXAMPLE_SRCS:.cpp=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
TEST_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, ${TEST_SRCS:.cpp=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
TEST_CU_WARNS := $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/, ${TEST_CU_SRCS:.cu=.o.$(WARNS_EXT)})
ALL_CXX_WARNS := $(CXX_WARNS) $(TOOL_WARNS) $(EXAMPLE_WARNS) $(TEST_WARNS)
ALL_CU_WARNS := $(CU_WARNS) $(TEST_CU_WARNS)
ALL_WARNS := $(ALL_CXX_WARNS) $(ALL_CU_WARNS)

EMPTY_WARN_REPORT := $(BUILD_DIR)/.$(WARNS_EXT)
NONEMPTY_WARN_REPORT := $(BUILD_DIR)/$(WARNS_EXT)

##############################
# Derive include and lib directories
##############################
CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR := $(CUDA_DIR)/include

CUDA_LIB_DIR :=
# add <cuda>/lib64 only if it exists
ifneq ("$(wildcard $(CUDA_DIR)/lib64)","")
    CUDA_LIB_DIR += $(CUDA_DIR)/lib64
endif
CUDA_LIB_DIR += $(CUDA_DIR)/lib

INCLUDE_DIRS += $(BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR) ./src ./include
ifneq ($(CPU_ONLY), 1)
    INCLUDE_DIRS += $(CUDA_INCLUDE_DIR)
    LIBRARY_DIRS += $(CUDA_LIB_DIR)
    LIBRARIES := cudart cublas curand
endif

LIBRARIES += glog gflags protobuf boost_system boost_filesystem m hdf5_hl hdf5 opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc opencv_core pthread

# handle IO dependencies
USE_LEVELDB ?= 1
USE_LMDB ?= 1
USE_OPENCV ?= 1

ifeq ($(USE_LEVELDB), 1)
    LIBRARIES += leveldb snappy
endif
ifeq ($(USE_LMDB), 1)
    LIBRARIES += lmdb
endif
ifeq ($(USE_OPENCV), 1)
    LIBRARIES += opencv_core opencv_highgui opencv_imgproc

    ifeq ($(OPENCV_VERSION), 3)
        LIBRARIES += opencv_imgcodecs
    endif

endif
PYTHON_LIBRARIES ?= boost_python python2.7
WARNINGS := -Wall -Wno-sign-compare

##############################
# Set build directories
##############################

DISTRIBUTE_DIR ?= distribute
DISTRIBUTE_SUBDIRS := $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/bin $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/lib
DIST_ALIASES := dist
ifneq ($(strip $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)),distribute)
        DIST_ALIASES += distribute
endif

ALL_BUILD_DIRS := $(sort $(BUILD_DIR) $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/, $(SRC_DIRS)) \
    $(addprefix $(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/, $(SRC_DIRS)) \
    $(LIB_BUILD_DIR) $(TEST_BIN_DIR) $(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR) $(LINT_OUTPUT_DIR) \
    $(DISTRIBUTE_SUBDIRS) $(PROTO_BUILD_INCLUDE_DIR))

##############################
# Set directory for Doxygen-generated documentation
##############################
DOXYGEN_CONFIG_FILE ?= ./.Doxyfile
# should be the same as OUTPUT_DIRECTORY in the .Doxyfile
DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR ?= ./doxygen
DOXYGEN_COMMAND ?= doxygen
# All the files that might have Doxygen documentation.
DOXYGEN_SOURCES := $(shell find \
    src/$(PROJECT) \
    include/$(PROJECT) \
    python/ \
    matlab/ \
    examples \
    tools \
    -name "*.cpp" -or -name "*.hpp" -or -name "*.cu" -or -name "*.cuh" -or \
        -name "*.py" -or -name "*.m")
DOXYGEN_SOURCES += $(DOXYGEN_CONFIG_FILE)


##############################
# Configure build
##############################

# Determine platform
UNAME := $(shell uname -s)
ifeq ($(UNAME), Linux)
    LINUX := 1
else ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
    OSX := 1
    OSX_MAJOR_VERSION := $(shell sw_vers -productVersion | cut -f 1 -d .)
    OSX_MINOR_VERSION := $(shell sw_vers -productVersion | cut -f 2 -d .)
endif

# Linux
ifeq ($(LINUX), 1)
    CXX ?= /usr/bin/g++
    GCCVERSION := $(shell $(CXX) -dumpversion | cut -f1,2 -d.)
    # older versions of gcc are too dumb to build boost with -Wuninitalized
    ifeq ($(shell echo | awk '{exit $(GCCVERSION) < 4.6;}'), 1)
        WARNINGS += -Wno-uninitialized
    endif
    # boost::thread is reasonably called boost_thread (compare OS X)
    # We will also explicitly add stdc++ to the link target.
    LIBRARIES += boost_thread stdc++
    VERSIONFLAGS += -Wl,-soname,$(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib
endif

# OS X:
# clang++ instead of g++
# libstdc++ for NVCC compatibility on OS X >= 10.9 with CUDA < 7.0
ifeq ($(OSX), 1)
    CXX := /usr/bin/clang++
    ifneq ($(CPU_ONLY), 1)
        CUDA_VERSION := $(shell $(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc -V | grep -o 'release [0-9.]*' | tr -d '[a-z ]')
        ifeq ($(shell echo | awk '{exit $(CUDA_VERSION) < 7.0;}'), 1)
            CXXFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++
            LINKFLAGS += -stdlib=libstdc++
        endif
        # clang throws this warning for cuda headers
        WARNINGS += -Wno-unneeded-internal-declaration
        # 10.11 strips DYLD_* env vars so link CUDA (rpath is available on 10.5+)
        OSX_10_OR_LATER   := $(shell [ $(OSX_MAJOR_VERSION) -ge 10 ] && echo true)
        OSX_10_5_OR_LATER := $(shell [ $(OSX_MINOR_VERSION) -ge 5 ] && echo true)
        ifeq ($(OSX_10_OR_LATER),true)
            ifeq ($(OSX_10_5_OR_LATER),true)
                LDFLAGS += -Wl,-rpath,$(CUDA_LIB_DIR)
            endif
        endif
    endif
    # gtest needs to use its own tuple to not conflict with clang
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DGTEST_USE_OWN_TR1_TUPLE=1
    # boost::thread is called boost_thread-mt to mark multithreading on OS X
    LIBRARIES += boost_thread-mt
    # we need to explicitly ask for the rpath to be obeyed
    ORIGIN := @loader_path
    VERSIONFLAGS += -Wl,-install_name,@rpath/$(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../../build/lib
else
    ORIGIN := \$$ORIGIN
endif

# Custom compiler
ifdef CUSTOM_CXX
    CXX := $(CUSTOM_CXX)
endif

# Static linking
ifneq (,$(findstring clang++,$(CXX)))
    STATIC_LINK_COMMAND := -Wl,-force_load $(STATIC_NAME)
else ifneq (,$(findstring g++,$(CXX)))
    STATIC_LINK_COMMAND := -Wl,--whole-archive $(STATIC_NAME) -Wl,--no-whole-archive
else
  # The following line must not be indented with a tab, since we are not inside a target
  $(error Cannot static link with the $(CXX) compiler)
endif

# Debugging
ifeq ($(DEBUG), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DDEBUG -g -O0
    NVCCFLAGS += -G
else
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DNDEBUG -O2
endif

# cuDNN acceleration configuration.
ifeq ($(USE_CUDNN), 1)
    LIBRARIES += cudnn
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_CUDNN
endif

# NCCL acceleration configuration
ifeq ($(USE_NCCL), 1)
    LIBRARIES += nccl
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_NCCL
endif

# configure IO libraries
ifeq ($(USE_OPENCV), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_OPENCV
endif
ifeq ($(USE_LEVELDB), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_LEVELDB
endif
ifeq ($(USE_LMDB), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_LMDB
ifeq ($(ALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DALLOW_LMDB_NOLOCK
endif
endif

# CPU-only configuration
ifeq ($(CPU_ONLY), 1)
    OBJS := $(PROTO_OBJS) $(CXX_OBJS)
    TEST_OBJS := $(TEST_CXX_OBJS)
    TEST_BINS := $(TEST_CXX_BINS)
    ALL_WARNS := $(ALL_CXX_WARNS)
    TEST_FILTER := --gtest_filter="-*GPU*"
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DCPU_ONLY
endif

# Python layer support
ifeq ($(WITH_PYTHON_LAYER), 1)
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DWITH_PYTHON_LAYER
    LIBRARIES += $(PYTHON_LIBRARIES)
endif

# BLAS configuration (default = ATLAS)
BLAS ?= atlas
ifeq ($(BLAS), mkl)
    # MKL
    LIBRARIES += mkl_rt
    COMMON_FLAGS += -DUSE_MKL
    MKLROOT ?= /opt/intel/mkl
    BLAS_INCLUDE ?= $(MKLROOT)/include
    BLAS_LIB ?= $(MKLROOT)/lib $(MKLROOT)/lib/intel64
else ifeq ($(BLAS), open)
    # OpenBLAS
    LIBRARIES += openblas
else
    # ATLAS
    ifeq ($(LINUX), 1)
        ifeq ($(BLAS), atlas)
            # Linux simply has cblas and atlas
            LIBRARIES += cblas atlas
        endif
    else ifeq ($(OSX), 1)
        # OS X packages atlas as the vecLib framework
        LIBRARIES += cblas
        # 10.10 has accelerate while 10.9 has veclib
        XCODE_CLT_VER := $(shell pkgutil --pkg-info=com.apple.pkg.CLTools_Executables | grep 'version' | sed 's/[^0-9]*\([0-9]\).*/\1/')
        XCODE_CLT_GEQ_7 := $(shell [ $(XCODE_CLT_VER) -gt 6 ] && echo 1)
        XCODE_CLT_GEQ_6 := $(shell [ $(XCODE_CLT_VER) -gt 5 ] && echo 1)
        ifeq ($(XCODE_CLT_GEQ_7), 1)
            BLAS_INCLUDE ?= /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/$(shell ls /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/ | sort | tail -1)/System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/A/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/A/Headers
        else ifeq ($(XCODE_CLT_GEQ_6), 1)
            BLAS_INCLUDE ?= /System/Library/Frameworks/Accelerate.framework/Versions/Current/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Headers/
            LDFLAGS += -framework Accelerate
        else
            BLAS_INCLUDE ?= /Users/sarah/caffe/OpenBLAS
                            #/System/Library/Frameworks/vecLib.framework/Versions/Current/Headers/
            LDFLAGS += -framework Accelerate 
            #vecLib
        endif
    endif
endif
INCLUDE_DIRS += $(BLAS_INCLUDE)
LIBRARY_DIRS += $(BLAS_LIB)

LIBRARY_DIRS += $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)

# Automatic dependency generation (nvcc is handled separately)
CXXFLAGS += -MMD -MP

# Complete build flags.
COMMON_FLAGS += $(foreach includedir,$(INCLUDE_DIRS),-I$(includedir))
CXXFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS)
NVCCFLAGS += -ccbin=$(CXX) -Xcompiler -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS)
# mex may invoke an older gcc that is too liberal with -Wuninitalized
MATLAB_CXXFLAGS := $(CXXFLAGS) -Wno-uninitialized
LINKFLAGS += -pthread -fPIC $(COMMON_FLAGS) $(WARNINGS)

USE_PKG_CONFIG ?= 0
ifeq ($(USE_PKG_CONFIG), 1)
    PKG_CONFIG := $(shell pkg-config opencv --libs)
else
    PKG_CONFIG :=
endif
LDFLAGS += $(foreach librarydir,$(LIBRARY_DIRS),-L$(librarydir)) $(PKG_CONFIG) \
        $(foreach library,$(LIBRARIES),-l$(library))
PYTHON_LDFLAGS := $(LDFLAGS) $(foreach library,$(PYTHON_LIBRARIES),-l$(library))

# 'superclean' target recursively* deletes all files ending with an extension
# in $(SUPERCLEAN_EXTS) below.  This may be useful if you've built older
# versions of Caffe that do not place all generated files in a location known
# to the 'clean' target.
#
# 'supercleanlist' will list the files to be deleted by make superclean.
#
# * Recursive with the exception that symbolic links are never followed, per the
# default behavior of 'find'.
SUPERCLEAN_EXTS := .so .a .o .bin .testbin .pb.cc .pb.h _pb2.py .cuo

# Set the sub-targets of the 'everything' target.
EVERYTHING_TARGETS := all py$(PROJECT) test warn lint
# Only build matcaffe as part of "everything" if MATLAB_DIR is specified.
ifneq ($(MATLAB_DIR),)
    EVERYTHING_TARGETS += mat$(PROJECT)
endif

##############################
# Define build targets
##############################
.PHONY: all lib test clean docs linecount lint lintclean tools examples $(DIST_ALIASES) \
    py mat py$(PROJECT) mat$(PROJECT) proto runtest \
    superclean supercleanlist supercleanfiles warn everything

all: lib tools examples

lib: $(STATIC_NAME) $(DYNAMIC_NAME)

everything: $(EVERYTHING_TARGETS)

linecount:
    cloc --read-lang-def=$(PROJECT).cloc \
        src/$(PROJECT) include/$(PROJECT) tools examples \
        python matlab

lint: $(EMPTY_LINT_REPORT)

lintclean:
    @ $(RM) -r $(LINT_OUTPUT_DIR) $(EMPTY_LINT_REPORT) $(NONEMPTY_LINT_REPORT)

docs: $(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR)
    @ cd ./docs ; ln -sfn ../$(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR)/html doxygen

$(DOXYGEN_OUTPUT_DIR): $(DOXYGEN_CONFIG_FILE) $(DOXYGEN_SOURCES)
    $(DOXYGEN_COMMAND) $(DOXYGEN_CONFIG_FILE)

$(EMPTY_LINT_REPORT): $(LINT_OUTPUTS) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    @ cat $(LINT_OUTPUTS) > $@
    @ if [ -s "$@" ]; then \
        cat $@; \
        mv $@ $(NONEMPTY_LINT_REPORT); \
        echo "Found one or more lint errors."; \
        exit 1; \
      fi; \
      $(RM) $(NONEMPTY_LINT_REPORT); \
      echo "No lint errors!";

$(LINT_OUTPUTS): $(LINT_OUTPUT_DIR)/%.lint.txt : % $(LINT_SCRIPT) | $(LINT_OUTPUT_DIR)
    @ mkdir -p $(dir $@)
    @ python $(LINT_SCRIPT) $< 2>&1 \
        | grep -v "^Done processing " \
        | grep -v "^Total errors found: 0" \
        > $@ \
        || true

test: $(TEST_ALL_BIN) $(TEST_ALL_DYNLINK_BIN) $(TEST_BINS)

tools: $(TOOL_BINS) $(TOOL_BIN_LINKS)

examples: $(EXAMPLE_BINS)

py$(PROJECT): py

py: $(PY$(PROJECT)_SO) $(PROTO_GEN_PY)

$(PY$(PROJECT)_SO): $(PY$(PROJECT)_SRC) $(PY$(PROJECT)_HXX) | $(DYNAMIC_NAME)
    @ echo CXX/LD -o $@ $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(PY$(PROJECT)_SRC) \
        -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) $(PYTHON_LDFLAGS) \
        -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../../build/lib

mat$(PROJECT): mat

mat: $(MAT$(PROJECT)_SO)

$(MAT$(PROJECT)_SO): $(MAT$(PROJECT)_SRC) $(STATIC_NAME)
    @ if [ -z "$(MATLAB_DIR)" ]; then \
        echo "MATLAB_DIR must be specified in $(CONFIG_FILE)" \
            "to build mat$(PROJECT)."; \
        exit 1; \
    fi
    @ echo MEX $<
    $(Q)$(MATLAB_DIR)/bin/mex $(MAT$(PROJECT)_SRC) \
            CXX="$(CXX)" \
            CXXFLAGS="\$$CXXFLAGS $(MATLAB_CXXFLAGS)" \
            CXXLIBS="\$$CXXLIBS $(STATIC_LINK_COMMAND) $(LDFLAGS)" -output $@
    @ if [ -f "$(PROJECT)_.d" ]; then \
        mv -f $(PROJECT)_.d $(BUILD_DIR)/${MAT$(PROJECT)_SO:.$(MAT_SO_EXT)=.d}; \
    fi

runtest: $(TEST_ALL_BIN)
    $(TOOL_BUILD_DIR)/caffe
    $(TEST_ALL_BIN) $(TEST_GPUID) --gtest_shuffle $(TEST_FILTER)

pytest: py
    cd python; python -m unittest discover -s caffe/test

mattest: mat
    cd matlab; $(MATLAB_DIR)/bin/matlab -nodisplay -r 'caffe.run_tests(), exit()'

warn: $(EMPTY_WARN_REPORT)

$(EMPTY_WARN_REPORT): $(ALL_WARNS) | $(BUILD_DIR)
    @ cat $(ALL_WARNS) > $@
    @ if [ -s "$@" ]; then \
        cat $@; \
        mv $@ $(NONEMPTY_WARN_REPORT); \
        echo "Compiler produced one or more warnings."; \
        exit 1; \
      fi; \
      $(RM) $(NONEMPTY_WARN_REPORT); \
      echo "No compiler warnings!";

$(ALL_WARNS): %.o.$(WARNS_EXT) : %.o

$(BUILD_DIR_LINK): $(BUILD_DIR)/.linked

# Create a target ".linked" in this BUILD_DIR to tell Make that the "build" link
# is currently correct, then delete the one in the OTHER_BUILD_DIR in case it
# exists and $(DEBUG) is toggled later.
$(BUILD_DIR)/.linked:
    @ mkdir -p $(BUILD_DIR)
    @ $(RM) $(OTHER_BUILD_DIR)/.linked
    @ $(RM) -r $(BUILD_DIR_LINK)
    @ ln -s $(BUILD_DIR) $(BUILD_DIR_LINK)
    @ touch $@

$(ALL_BUILD_DIRS): | $(BUILD_DIR_LINK)
    @ mkdir -p $@

$(DYNAMIC_NAME): $(OBJS) | $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo LD -o $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) -shared -o $@ $(OBJS) $(VERSIONFLAGS) $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS)
    @ cd $(BUILD_DIR)/lib; rm -f $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT);   ln -s $(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT) $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT)

$(STATIC_NAME): $(OBJS) | $(LIB_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo AR -o $@
    $(Q)ar rcs $@ $(OBJS)

$(BUILD_DIR)/%.o: %.cpp | $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
    @ echo CXX $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $< $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ 2> $@.$(WARNS_EXT) \
        || (cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT); exit 1)
    @ cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT)

$(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/%.pb.o: $(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/%.pb.cc $(PROTO_GEN_HEADER) \
        | $(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo CXX $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $< $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ 2> $@.$(WARNS_EXT) \
        || (cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT); exit 1)
    @ cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT)

$(BUILD_DIR)/cuda/%.o: %.cu | $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
    @ echo NVCC $<
    $(Q)$(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc $(NVCCFLAGS) $(CUDA_ARCH) -M $< -o ${@:.o=.d} \
        -odir $(@D)
    $(Q)$(CUDA_DIR)/bin/nvcc $(NVCCFLAGS) $(CUDA_ARCH) -c $< -o $@ 2> $@.$(WARNS_EXT) \
        || (cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT); exit 1)
    @ cat $@.$(WARNS_EXT)

$(TEST_ALL_BIN): $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $(TEST_OBJS) $(GTEST_OBJ) \
        | $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(TEST_BIN_DIR)
    @ echo CXX/LD -o $@ $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $(TEST_OBJS) $(GTEST_OBJ) \
        -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib

$(TEST_CU_BINS): $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/%.testbin: $(TEST_CU_BUILD_DIR)/%.o \
    $(GTEST_OBJ) | $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(TEST_BIN_DIR)
    @ echo LD $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $< $(GTEST_OBJ) \
        -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib

$(TEST_CXX_BINS): $(TEST_BIN_DIR)/%.testbin: $(TEST_CXX_BUILD_DIR)/%.o \
    $(GTEST_OBJ) | $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(TEST_BIN_DIR)
    @ echo LD $<
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(TEST_MAIN_SRC) $< $(GTEST_OBJ) \
        -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib

# Target for extension-less symlinks to tool binaries with extension '*.bin'.
$(TOOL_BUILD_DIR)/%: $(TOOL_BUILD_DIR)/%.bin | $(TOOL_BUILD_DIR)
    @ $(RM) $@
    @ ln -s $(notdir $<) $@

$(TOOL_BINS): %.bin : %.o | $(DYNAMIC_NAME)
    @ echo CXX/LD -o $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) $< -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) $(LDFLAGS) \
        -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../lib

$(EXAMPLE_BINS): %.bin : %.o | $(DYNAMIC_NAME)
    @ echo CXX/LD -o $@
    $(Q)$(CXX) $< -o $@ $(LINKFLAGS) -l$(LIBRARY_NAME) $(LDFLAGS) \
        -Wl,-rpath,$(ORIGIN)/../../lib

proto: $(PROTO_GEN_CC) $(PROTO_GEN_HEADER)

$(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/%.pb.cc $(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/%.pb.h : \
        $(PROTO_SRC_DIR)/%.proto | $(PROTO_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo PROTOC $<
    $(Q)protoc --proto_path=$(PROTO_SRC_DIR) --cpp_out=$(PROTO_BUILD_DIR) $<

$(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR)/%_pb2.py : $(PROTO_SRC_DIR)/%.proto \
        $(PY_PROTO_INIT) | $(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR)
    @ echo PROTOC \(python\) $<
    $(Q)protoc --proto_path=$(PROTO_SRC_DIR) --python_out=$(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR) $<

$(PY_PROTO_INIT): | $(PY_PROTO_BUILD_DIR)
    touch $(PY_PROTO_INIT)

clean:
    @- $(RM) -rf $(ALL_BUILD_DIRS)
    @- $(RM) -rf $(OTHER_BUILD_DIR)
    @- $(RM) -rf $(BUILD_DIR_LINK)
    @- $(RM) -rf $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)
    @- $(RM) $(PY$(PROJECT)_SO)
    @- $(RM) $(MAT$(PROJECT)_SO)

supercleanfiles:
    $(eval SUPERCLEAN_FILES := $(strip \
            $(foreach ext,$(SUPERCLEAN_EXTS), $(shell find . -name '*$(ext)' \
            -not -path './data/*'))))

supercleanlist: supercleanfiles
    @ \
    if [ -z "$(SUPERCLEAN_FILES)" ]; then \
        echo "No generated files found."; \
    else \
        echo $(SUPERCLEAN_FILES) | tr ' ' '\n'; \
    fi

superclean: clean supercleanfiles
    @ \
    if [ -z "$(SUPERCLEAN_FILES)" ]; then \
        echo "No generated files found."; \
    else \
        echo "Deleting the following generated files:"; \
        echo $(SUPERCLEAN_FILES) | tr ' ' '\n'; \
        $(RM) $(SUPERCLEAN_FILES); \
    fi

$(DIST_ALIASES): $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)

$(DISTRIBUTE_DIR): all py | $(DISTRIBUTE_SUBDIRS)
    # add proto
    cp -r src/caffe/proto $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/
    # add include
    cp -r include $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/
    mkdir -p $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/include/caffe/proto
    cp $(PROTO_GEN_HEADER_SRCS) $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/include/caffe/proto
    # add tool and example binaries
    cp $(TOOL_BINS) $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/bin
    cp $(EXAMPLE_BINS) $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/bin
    # add libraries
    cp $(STATIC_NAME) $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/lib
    install -m 644 $(DYNAMIC_NAME) $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/lib
    cd $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/lib; rm -f $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT);   ln -s $(DYNAMIC_VERSIONED_NAME_SHORT) $(DYNAMIC_NAME_SHORT)
    # add python - it's not the standard way, indeed...
    cp -r python $(DISTRIBUTE_DIR)/python

-include $(DEPS)
```

Makefile.config

```
# cuDNN acceleration switch (uncomment to build with cuDNN).
# USE_CUDNN := 1

# CPU-only switch (uncomment to build without GPU support).
CPU_ONLY := 1

# uncomment to disable IO dependencies and corresponding data layers
USE_OPENCV := 0
# USE_LEVELDB := 0
# USE_LMDB := 0

# Uncomment if you're using OpenCV 3
OPENCV_VERSION := 3

# CUDA directory contains bin/ and lib/ directories that we need.
CUDA_DIR := /usr/local/cuda
# On Ubuntu 14.04, if cuda tools are installed via
# "sudo apt-get install nvidia-cuda-toolkit" then use this instead:
# CUDA_DIR := /usr

# CUDA architecture setting: going with all of them.
# For CUDA < 6.0, comment the *_50 lines for compatibility.
CUDA_ARCH := -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_20 \
        -gencode arch=compute_20,code=sm_21 \
        -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 \
        -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=sm_50 \
        -gencode arch=compute_50,code=compute_50



BLAS := blas

BLAS_INCLUDE := /Users/sarah/caffe/OpenBLAS
BLAS_LIB := /Users/sarah/caffe/OpenBLAS

PYTHON_INCLUDE := /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/include/ /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/include/python2.7

PYTHON_LIB := /usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.13/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/

WITH_PYTHON_LAYER := 1

# Whatever else you find you need goes here.
INCLUDE_DIRS :=  /usr/local/include /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/include/ $(PYTHON_INCLUDE) /usr/local/opt/opencv3/include
LIBRARY_DIRS :=  /usr/local/lib /usr/lib /Developer/NVIDIA/CUDA-8.0/lib/ $(PYTHON_LIB) /usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib

# If Homebrew is installed at a non standard location (for example your home directory) and you use it for general dependencies
# INCLUDE_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/include
# LIBRARY_DIRS += $(shell brew --prefix)/lib

# Uncomment to use `pkg-config` to specify OpenCV library paths.
# (Usually not necessary -- OpenCV libraries are normally installed in one of the above $LIBRARY_DIRS.)
# USE_PKG_CONFIG := 1

BUILD_DIR := build
DISTRIBUTE_DIR := distribute

TEST_GPUID := 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just a couple of hints and guesses.

- This isn't necessarily a libc++/libstd++ inconsistency.
- `opencv_imgcodecs` is only available in OpenCV 3+, so that may make some problems.
- If you checked the opencv libraries and they were all linked to `libc++`, check if this command `ld -lopencv_highgui`, and for the other libraries as well, won't tell you the library is not found.
- Another thing to check is making sure you only have **one** OpenCV installation, sometimes a conflicting copy may cause these problems.
- You may also try to compile a standalone OpenCV example code, to make sure this is a problem with Caffe.
- `opencv_imgcodecs` is only available in OpenCV 3+, so that may make some problems.
- One last thing: remove everything, enable the cpu only mode to get rid of CUDA dependency, and this time use the latest version of everything, specifically: Latest Xcode command line tools and OpenCV3.

Posting your `Makefile` in your question could help, too.

Comment: thank you for all the tips! 
i uninstalled all opencv versions (i did have two) and reinstalled only opencv 3 using homebrew.
the command `ld -lopencv_highgui` still returns `ld: library not found for -lopencv_highgui` – how do i fix this?

Comment: (i also added the makefile and makefile.config)

Comment: @sarah as the library file is not in a standard location, `ld` fails to find it. But adding the library path, as you have done in Makefile.config, should fix that: `ld -L/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib -lopencv_highgui` should print a couple of warnings instead of that error. If that's the case, you can try compiling again, and if you still get the same error, check if this new OpenCV lib files inside `/usr/local/opt/opencv3/lib` have correct libc++ too.

Answer (score 1):

You can set `LDFLAGS` before execute `make all`

`` $ LDFLAGS="`pkg-config --libs protobuf` `pkg-config --libs opencv`"
$ make all ``